# Fitting a string into a predetermined pattern?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column that looks like:

```
A002
A0011
A0001
A0001A
A2
A3A
A02
```

and need to fit it into the format A00XXY 
i.e.:

```
A0002
A0011
A0001
A0001A
A0002
A0003A
A0002
```

I currently have

```
df.col.str.lstrip('A0')
for x in df.col.str.contains(r'[0-9]\w{1}$'):
    if x:
        df.col = 'A000' + df.col
    else:
        df.col = 'A00' + df.col
```

But this becomes recursive? What would be the best method to do this?

Comment: The output is not all in format `A00XXY` ?

Comment: Sorry, formatting 1 to 01 so X to A000X if X is singular and XX to A00XX and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely generalize this, so it will work in all cases, I will take some extra steps and `regex` to come to your expected output:

```
df['Start_letter'] = df['Col'].str.extract('(^[A-Za-z])').fillna('')              # Extract the first letter
df['End_letter'] = df['Col'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]$)').fillna('')                # Extract the last letter
df['Nums'] = df['Col'].str.replace('[A-Za-z]', '').apply(lambda x: x.zfill(4))    # Extract the numbers between the letters
df['Col'] = df['Start_letter'] + df['Nums'] + df['End_letter']

df = df.iloc[:, :1]
```

---

```
      Col
0   A0002
1   A0011
2   A0001
3  A0001A
4   A0002
5  A0003A
6   A0002
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have at lead pandas 0.20, `Series.str.replace` can use a match object via a callable. So you can do:

```
df['col'] = df.col.str.replace(r'A([0-9]{0,4})(\S*)',
                               lambda m: "A00{:02d}{}".format(int(m.group(1)), m.group(2)))
```

If you have an older version of pandas, you can replace the values:

```
df['col'] = ["A00{:02d}{}".format(int(m.group(1)), m.group(2))
             for m in [re.match(r'A([0-9]{0,4})(\S*)', k) for k in df.col]]
```